# MySql Update Query is Deleting Rows

Tags: mysql, sql-update, sql-delete, aws-aurora-serverless

I am trying to update rows (remove hyphen and after hyphen all characters from column **str_column**) using query -

```
UPDATE table_name
SET str_column = SUBSTRING(str_column, 0, LENGTH(str_column) - 2)
WHERE str_column = '561279-1';
```

but above query is deleting matched rows instead of updating.

I am not able to understand, how update query can delete rows??

Comment: This query selects rows from the table. It does not delete and it does not update anything.

Comment: sorry added wrong query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The substring has to begin with 1 not with 0

in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring) is clearly stated

> A value of 0 for pos returns an empty string.

example:

> ```
> CREATE tABLE table_name (str_column varchar(20))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ('561279-1')
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE table_name
> SET str_column = SUBSTRING(str_column, 1, LENGTH(str_column) - 2)
> WHERE str_column = '561279-1';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table_name
> ```
>
> ```
> | str_column |
> | :--------- |
> | 561279     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4ea6b42d9814cf3b62e8e6633423e88e)*

Comment: I got it but if I am using SUBSTRING function starting from 0 index then str_column should be set to null (or empty string) not delete row. right??